# С++20 modules code style

Tags: c++, модули, code-style, c++20

В связи с добавлением модулей в `c++20`, нужно теперь писать реализацию в отдельном файле(`.cpp`), или `codestyle` вышел на новый уровень?

Comment: давайте пусть модули утрясутся, а там и решим. А пока даже стандартная библиотека толком не переведена.

Comment: Компиляторы так ещё и не договорились о расширении этих файлов.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков при чем тут расширение? Вопрос про codestyle.......

Comment: При том, что MSVC у меня не коимильнёт модуль в .cpp а только в нужном расширении файла.

Comment: Какой .cpp чел.... .cpp - это реализация. А объявление класса/функции должно быть в .ixx